# Rails integration tests using session-store

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, session-store

My application is using ActiveReccord session-store with a custom session class. This is all working fine in production and development.

When running integration tests however, this does not seem to work. No Session gets created at all. As i'm depending on the custom session class, therefore i can not switch to cookie-store for testing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this? I am also running into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

try setting your test `domain`

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_yourkey', domain: Rails.env.test? ? '127.0.0.1' : 'yourdomain.com'
```

Comment: This does not seem to help.